# Why do we say that a transition state that resembles a stable species in free energy also resembles it in structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My textbook states," According to the Hammond-Leffler postulate, the transition- state structure for a step that is uphill in energy should show a strong resemblance to the structure of the product of that step."

Also stating,"One way that the postulate can be stated is to say that structure of a transition state resembles the stable species that is nearest to it in free energy. For example, in a highly **endergonic** step the transition state lies close to the products in free energy,and we assume,therefore,that **it resembles the products of that step in structure as well**. "
(Source:Solomons' Organic Chemistry
Book by Craig B. Fryhle, Scott A. Snyder, and T. W. Graham Solomons)

Comment: If you quote from a book, please cite it.

Comment: That is quite literally what the Hammond postulate says ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammond%27s_postulate)). So the direct answer to why we say that is because that's what the postulate says. Are you asking about the justification for the postulate?

Comment: Yes , I meant is there any logical explanation for it?Or should we just accept it just because it's a postulate..

Comment: Because it seems quite reasonable at first. Of course there might very different structures with similar energy, but it is unlikely. And even more so if the structures lie along a reaction path.

Comment: Fallon, it is clear to you that the transition state is higher in energy than any other species involved (reactants, metastable intermediates that can be eventually isolated, products) involved?

Comment: Yes , I think the answer is really helpful and clears my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT for a different approach:

The energy of a quantum mechanical system of nuclei and electrons is governed by the positions of the pieces. So, we're looking at the energy associated with the wave functions of all the pieces.

For two species that are similar in structure, the idea is that those two structures lead to relatively similar solutions of the wave functions. If the wave functions are similar, the energies of the particles described by those wave functions must be similar as well.

Comment: The use of early and late makes this answer very obscure. At least to me.

Comment: Early and late are standard terms when discussing the Hammond Postulate. I tried to relate early to "early on the reaction coordinate." Do you have any specific suggestions for improving the answer?

Comment: Because isn't clear to which logic you refer to, at the very start. Then what you said reiterate the postulate. Perhaps I am wrong but the "answer" should be that in the comment by @orthocresol, integrated by my comment. The problem is how to explain something intuitive to OP. As I said one can imagine exceptions or violations, of course. But it should be natural to relate similar energy to similar structures, and this is what the postulate does.

Comment: I see what you mean. Let me try again.

Comment: @Alchimista Better?

Comment: I think my comment was not all that helpful! It was meant more to clarify the question...

Comment: @orthocresol is what I mean. And I've tried to integrate it to provide what it seems obvious to me.

Comment: Yes somehow it is better. It can holds also for classical system like bodies and springs. More to the OP now: perhaps I am the naive one, but it seems a very reasonable postulate if one has the context clear. Perhaps it is not, at the end it is named after Hammond, but it is how I always saw/interpreted it.

Comment: @Alchimista In the end, it's just a mathematical statement. For a smooth, single-valued function $f$ of $n$ variables, small perturbations $\delta n$ led to small perturbations of $\delta f$ which can be determined from (and in some sense, capped by) the partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Right. The movement done is the association to structure.